# Instance failure while connecting to SQL Server c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to connect to sql server from c# and I keep getting these error pointing at a specific line saying "Instance failure". What could I be doing wrong? I have attached the error log below.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection con = null;
    con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=VAIO\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Employee;User ID=****;Password=****");

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("employeedetails",con))
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            sda.Fill(dt);//Instance failure at this specific line
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //Populate your DropDownList
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;

                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Error log -

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: Instance failure.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at _Default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite15\Default.aspx.cs:line 30
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)}
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to the SQLExpress server using the credentials you pass int the `SqlConnection`? By the way you should avoid *for security reasons*
 to post the credentials you connect to any system, even if this system is a development environment.

Comment: @Christos:- Yeah that's the same connection string I used for another webproject and it worked just fine. Thanks again for the security advise.

Comment: You are welcome !

Comment: please paste entire error

Comment: @jessica If you replace this `VAIO\\SQLEXPRESS` with this `.\SQLEXPRESS` do you see any change?

Comment: @Christos:- I have pasted the error logs below. Would you kindly have a look at it?

Comment: @jessica Sure thing, but please try the change I mentioned before and let me know. That seems problem to me is the fact that you have used the same connection string and it did work in another project. If that I suggested not work, you could try to restart your sql server service and try again.

Comment: @Christos:- Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: You are welcome. What worked the restart or the change of connection string?

Comment: @Christos:- Yes I changed the connection string to the one you suggested. It worked. But strangely, I still wonder why my other project was working fine with the connection string I used before.

Comment: Hmm...I don't know. We should investigate it further why the same connection string  worked in one probejct and didn't work in the other.

Comment: @Christos:- I shall do a stepwise debugging and check my other code. Thanks again. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @jessica You are welcome. I am glad that I helped :)